# Waiting time in S-function

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I am trying to create a flashing procedure in Simulink using a S-function (C language) and I need to send some frames and the time between 2 consecutive frames should be lets say 200 milisconds. How can I implement this waiting time? Is there any possibility of implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update something every 200ms, put your S-Function into a subsystem which is triggered every 200s.

Comment: Or give it a 200ms sample time and call the corresponding model_stepX function every 200ms. (see multitasking grt main)

Comment: I want this waiting time to be in the function, I don

Comment: If you let it wait in the function, no other block can be executed. Is this intended?

Comment: I want this waiting time to be in the function, not the function to be executed every 200 ms

Comment: You should use the [mdlGetTimeOfNextVarHit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/mdlgettimeofnextvarhit.html) method, within the S-Function, to specify when the block should next be sampled.