# Wait using s-function

Tags: matlab, wait, simulink, s-function

I am using a s-function built in Simulink and I need to implement a waiting time. For example I need to do this :

```
send the first frame    
wait 20 ms
send the second frame
wait 20 ms
send  third frame
```

How could I establish this waiting time between 2 frames. I am using C language and a Level-1 Matlab S-function.

Comment: This is the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785027/waiting-time-in-s-function).  The answer hasn't changed: you can either make the S-Function discrete and specify the sample time, or use the [mdlGetTimeOfNextSampleHit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/mdlgettimeofnextvarhit.html) method to change the sample time each time the block is called.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is very difficult to get millisecond accuracy. it depends a lot on your hardware, OS, proccesses running..

you could try to achieve it by simply using the pause command

```
send the first frame    
pause(0.020)
send the second frame
pause(0.020)
send  third frame
```

or using timer objects http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerclass.html

both solutions are not accurate. the best solution would be to base your timing in external events. is there any event triggered after sending each frame?

Comment: Yes, I have a trigger after sending a frame and this is why I need to wait to be sure that the trigger was triggered.

Comment: generally you can attach functions to handle events. does your frame object have such event handlers? you could inspect the frame and find out if it is possible.

Comment: maybe you've already visited this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sample-time-1.html but i guess there is what you need. maybe the "S-Function Callback Methods" section.